# activeMQ with logstash

Tags: activemq-classic, logstash

can activeMQ work with logstash?

I was switching from  rabbitMQ to  activeMQ,  and trying to make logstash to work with activeMQ..

In my previous rabbitMQ,  I have something like:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    host => "hostname"
    queue => "queue1"
    key => "key1"
    exchange => "ex1"
    type => "all"
    durable => true
    auto_delete => false
    exclusive => false
    format => "json_event"
    debug => false
  }
}

filter {....}
```

on logstash webpage -> doc,  it does not show  activeMQ supported as input...

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use (not tried it myself) the [STOMP](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/inputs/stomp) input. [ActiveMQ supports stomp](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp).